# How to import data from zillow to drupal and How to integrate walk score into your drupal site?

Tags: drupal, zillow

I built a real estate website using Drupal 7. The website is fully functional (http://www.HousesInUSA.com). Users can register and create listings for their house(s). Additionally, they can create and/or contribute to blogs, forums, polls and groups. The website offer three options with different features.  My next goal is to import data from Zillow api to this website. I would love some help, if anyone has experience or has worked with Zillow and walk score.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into http://drupal.org/project/migrate. Using it, you can migrate data from any source into Drupal. It's even supports resuming.

// Off-topic

How did you made search box on http://www.housesinusa.com/, using only views or custom module?

Comment: I used views module to build the side search and search page.